# Binary sort on a vector

Tags: c++, search

I am sorting my vector of strings in the following way, so that I can binary_search it later.

```
std::vector<std::string> vec;
...........
...........
std::sort(vec.begin(),vec.end());
```

Now I am searching it as follows.

```
if (!std::binary_search(vec.begin(), vec.end(), "SomeString"));
{
    //Not Found
}
else
{
    //Found
}
```

However, it seems that the binary_search is not working, and it returns a false to the "strings" that are present in the vector.

What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: What are the contents of `vec` ?

Comment: Post the code where you are doing this.

Comment: The contents of the vector are strings `std::vector<std::string> vec`;

Comment: @Kunal What code would u like me to post . I do not have a predicate

Comment: @Rajeshwar I mean what strings are inside `vec`, may be its not present ? I don't see a problem with posted code

Comment: The smallest *working* (i.e. failing with your error) example you can get would be the right thing to post. There is nothing obviously wrong with the code, assuming that it is a `vector<string>`, and that it contains `SomeString`, that code should find it.

Comment: Was an honest mistake dont know why the -1 ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look at the very last character on this line:

```
if(!std::binary_search(vec.begin(),vec.end(),"SomeString"));
```

You have a misplaced `;` there. Remove it and test again.

Comment: Ahh, good one, I didn't see that +1

Comment: I dint see that - Thanks for pointing it out- Marked as answer